# Remap select window 2 in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, key-mapping

In *tmux* you can switch to window 2 with <kbd>prefix_key + 2</kbd>. I'd like to press rather <kbd>prefix_key + u</kbd>.

I tried in *.tmux.conf* this:

```
bind-key u 2
```

and this:

```
bind-key u select-window -t 2
```

Which doesn't work. Is it possible to create such mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a colon to select based on index. Try this:

```
bind-key u select-window -t :2
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: Did you reload your .tmux.conf? Also keep in mind window index are zero based unless you change with:

    set-option -g base-index 1

Comment: I exited tmux and lxterminal several times. I know it's zero based.

Comment: `tmux` instances share the same tmux session, _.tmux.conf is only read when the session is started. Make sure that the `tmux list-sessions` list is empty, or explicitly run `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` after starting `tmux`.

Comment: @Thor Thanks a lot. `source-file` was necessary.